# How to print numeric value in php looping where two mysqli data are same?

Tags: php

I have a mysql Table like this:

```
 BookId     Name    Athor   Title
 E2         HTML    zorce   Knowing HTML
 E3         HTML    zorce   Knowing HTML
 E4         CSS3    Zahid   Knowing CSS3
 E5         CSS3    Zahid   Knowing CSS3
 E6         CSS3    Zahid   Knowing CSS3
 E7         CSS3    Zahid   Knowing CSS3
```

I need to view result like this:

```
E2
1
HTML
Zorce
Knowing HTML
E3
2
HTML
Zorce
Knowing HTML
E4
1
CSS3
Zahid
Knowing CSS3
E5
2
CSS3
Zahid
Knowing CSS3
E6
3
CSS3
Zahid
Knowing CSS3
E7
4
CSS3
Zahid
Knowing CSS3
```

This is my php code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


echo $r['BookId'] ."<br>";

//.....................?..???
echo $r['Name'] ."<br>";
echo $r['title'] ."<br>";
echo $r['Author'] ."<br>";
echo"<br><br>";

   }
```

Please tell : How to solve this problem ?..

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbT7n.png]

[image]

Comment: Don't make us sweat it - what column are you comparing to come up with your numbers?

Comment: A little more explanation, please! What do the numbers mean?!

Comment: Is the image what you want the data to output as?

Comment: I need to add number when one-more data will be same without BookId.

Comment: Actually. I want to print extra numeric value when multiple data will be same then assign 12 3 4.......like number. else 1